# Java: 2 Classes, One Main(Tester) and other class(methods). Getting input from tester and passing to other class's ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

New to this website and coding in java in general. I have about 5 months experience from last year's classes. and another half spent in python. We have reached our second lab this semester and I have ran into a slight problem that my new professor refuses to help / guide with.

The lab is as described.

Make a to do list that has 2 classes. One class (the main tester one) takes in all the IO and gives all the output. The other class contains the todo list itself (arraylist) and provides methods for the main class to call on. The scanner object is in the main tester class. the arraylist is in the other class.

The following commands of input are necessary.

List, New, Change, Delete, Quit.

The program basically prompts the message to add something to your to do list. add whatever the whole line is. Then modify it as you do them.

My current questions regards how to take the input from the tester program and pass it to the other class to store into the arraylist. We have done labs where they were all in the main class and I would just add with the method calls of the Arraylist class. however now we must do it this way and I am having troubles getting them to communicate. Im guessing that I just have some sort of constructor wrong or some object misreferenced. Here is a short snippet of what I have.

(Main Tester Class)
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ToDoTester
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);


    ToDo info = new ToDo();

    while(true)
    {
      System.out.println("* * * Start To Do List * * *");
      System.out.println("Enter a command (List, New, Change, Done) or Quit 
");   

      String x = in.next();


      if(x.equals("List"))
      {
         System.out.println(info.getList()); 
         //Print out the array list
      }

      else if(x.equals("New"))
      {
         //System.out.println(info.addList(addedListOption)); 
         //Add new thing to do to arraylist
      }
```

(Other Class With Methods)

```
public class ToDo {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayLst<String>();

    ToDoTester scan = new ToDoTester();

    private String list;

    public void addList() {
         //tring takeIn = ToDoTester.scan.next();
         //data.add(scan.nextLine());
    }
    public String getList() {
        System.out.println(data.size());
        return list;
    }
}
```

I realize this may be a very nooby problem and perhaps i'm making more of a deal out of it than I have to. But i truly want to understand what I am doing and this new professor as compared to my old one is slightly worse in the helping understanding department. Thus, i come here for help, not for someone doing my work! So any help would be appreciated and I can supply any other information as needed. Can even post a picture of the lab if necessary or easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original answer

You are doing well, but you probably forgot that we can pass in objects to methods via method arguments.

```
class ToDo {
    public void addToList(String newToDo) {
        data.add(newToDo);
    }
}

class ToDoTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        } else if (x.equals("New")) {
            info.addToList(in.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

### Expanded answer

Here is a simplified version of how I would perform the task.

As I mentioned in the comments, there is room for improvement: we can replace the switch with the command pattern, we can separate the entry point from our domain classes, we can handle exceptions more accurately, we can customise the output messages more elaborately.

Anyway, first take a look at this, and then let me know if you want to see a more enhanced version.

```
final class ToDoTester {
    private final Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ToDo toDo = new ToDo();
        final ToDoTester toDoTester = new ToDoTester();

        final Scanner reader = toDoTester.getReader();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:");

            switch (reader.nextLine()) {
                case "List":
                    toDoTester.display(toDo.list());
                    break;
                case "New":
                    toDo.add(toDoTester.readToDo());
                    break;
                case "Change":
                    final Pair<Integer, String> input = toDoTester.readInputToChange();
                    toDo.update(input.getKey(), input.getValue());
                    break;
                case "Delete":
                    toDo.remove(toDoTester.readIndex());
                    break;
                case "Quit":
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect choice, let's try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    public Scanner getReader() {
        return reader;
    }

    public void display(List<String> list) {
        IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> String.format("[%d] %s", i, list.get(i)))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public Pair<Integer, String> readInputToChange() {
        return new Pair<>(readIndex(), readToDo());
    }

    public String readToDo() {
        System.out.println("Enter a to-do:");
        return reader.nextLine();
    }

    public int readIndex() {
        System.out.println("Enter the index of the to-do:");
        return Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
    }

}

final class ToDo {
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String toDo) {
        list.add(toDo);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        validatePosition(position);
        list.remove(position);
    }

    public void update(int position, String substitute) {
        validatePosition(position);
        list.set(position, substitute);
    }

    private void validatePosition(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= list.size()) {
            // should be thrown an exception
            System.out.println("Incorrect input.");
        }
    }

    public List<String> list() {
        return new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

}
```

An example of execution:

```
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
List
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
New
Enter a to-do:
first to-do
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
List
[0] first to-do
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
Change
Enter the index of the to-do:
0
Enter a to-do:
my first to-do
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
List
[0] my first to-do
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
Delete
Enter the index of the to-do:
0
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
List
Enter a command (List, New, Change, Delete) or Quit:
```

Comment: Ahh Yes.. Im quite rusty over the summer, I figured it was something small and simple I was missing. But thank you! and yes, I would be interested in correcting those as well. Open to any suggestions too. We will be starting on something called inheritance this week coming up, so knowing getting these basics down is crucial to me! Im currently writing the rest of the else if statements for the remaining commands (Change, Delete, Quit). So whenever you have the time point them out!

Comment: @RobertLenko you need to revise `ToDoTester`, the class now is just a wrapper for the `main` method, it doesn't have any method to read input for a new to-do element, to show the welcome message, etc.

Comment: @RobertLenko I think there should the 3rd class, let's call it `Application`, it will contain the entry point - the `main` method where your 2 other classes will be initialised, and the `while` loop will be declared. In the loop, you will be needed to define the logic for exit. Any other action should be delegated to either `ToDo` or `ToDoTester`.

Comment: @RobertLenko It would be nice if the classes were unaware of each other. One class provides input in `Strings`, the other takes that input via method arguments. The former doesn't know about the to-do list, while the latter doesn't (and shouldn't) care how the input was obtained. So they are completely independent and can work autonomously.

Comment: @RobertLenko After that, you can implement [the command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which perfectly fits your commands (List, New, Change, Delete).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I see what you are talking about making a third class, however I'm capped at a limit of only 2 classes for this lab unfortunately. I have written more code since last night and got the adding and list function to work ok. Im now working on the delete command and it is only deleting the first item in the arraylist, not the user inputted integer.

Comment: I feel this is due in part because my instance variable is initialized to 0, thus it deleted the 0 place in the array list. However Im unsure how to pass the integer that was input from the main class to the delete method properly. I tried storing the integer in a variable in the main class, then passing that variable to the method argument, however no luck there, at least with my current knowledge.

Comment: @RobertLenko join this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/179712/robert-lenkos-question so we can talk there

Comment: I tried to join and it said I need 20 reputation to talk.. lol. I seen your message in there though, you could post another form of communication in there if you want that I could go to.

Comment: chats are supposed to stop flooding in the comments, I didn't know that such limitations existed. I'll update the answer

Comment: It is ok, I have it figured out. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why it was unchecked. I rechecked it! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your todo class must have arraylist and puplic methods, that are get string (for add method) or int (for delete) or nothing (for list) as arguments, and operate on arraylist.  Your ToDoTester class must contain example of todo class (ToDo info = new ToDo();) and operate on its methods in loop. Hope that helps